# Why is my Kendo Grid only showing one row at a time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

My grid contracts vertically to show barely one row at a time. It looks like this:

[image: My midget grid]
The bottom grey bar, with "1 - 2 of 2 items" also has the pager on the right hand side, and there is a large white area under that bar that belongs to the grid, contrasted to the grey background everywhere else that doesn't belong to the grid.

It's a bit long, but here is my grid definition, before someone takes half a millisecond to ask for code:

```
@model VehicleMovementBatchIndexModel
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@using ParkPay.TheBridge.ViewModels
@using GridEditMode = Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridEditMode
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<VehicleMovementBatchIndexItem>()
                       .Name("index-grid")
                       .Columns(columns =>
                                    {
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.FileName).Title("File Name");
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.FileContentHash).Title("File Content MD5");
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.FileReportDate).Title("File Report Date").Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}").Width(180);
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.Imported).Title("Imported").Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}").Width(130);
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.ResultMessage).Title("Result").Width(110);
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.Remarks);
                                        columns.Command(cmd => cmd.Destroy().Text("Delete")).Width(100);
                                        columns.Command(cmd => cmd.Custom("Prepare").Click("PrepareBatch")).Width(90);
                                    })
                       .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 480px;" })
                       .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
                                          .ToolBar(toolbar =>
                       {
                           toolbar.Save();
                       })
                       .Filterable()
                       .Pageable()
                       .Scrollable()
                       .Sortable()
                       .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                       .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
                       .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                             .Ajax()
                                             .ServerOperation(false)
                                             .Batch(true)
                                             .PageSize(20)
                                             .Events(events => events.Error("kendoGridErrorHandler"))
                                             .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
                                             .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "VehicleMovementBatch"))
                                             .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("BatchDelete", "VehicleMovementBatch"))
                                             .Update(update => update.Action("BatchUpdate", "VehicleMovementBatch"))
                                   ))
```

Comment: Make sure that your css doesn't override kendo's styles.

Comment: I only have three css files, and the last two are Kendo.

Comment: @ProfK that doesn't matter - it could still have a conflicting style. I know the default MVC stylesheet does not play well with the kendo stylesheets.

Comment: Have you attached a CSS inspector? There's nothing in your sample code that would lead to this problem. Without some sort of demo page, there's no way for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try with the below code snippet?

Method 1:

Please update ".scrollable()" code with the below code snippet.

```
.Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Enabled(true).Height(480))
```

Method 2 :

Please try with the below code. If this code will work then your third CSS file affect this grid otherwise its not.

```
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 480px !important;" })
```

Let me know if any concern.

Answer (score 2):

- Try it with a different kendo skin?
- Check if you are using the same order to include css and js files.
  Sometimes wrong order of files or adding jquery two times might give
  unexpected outcome. See this for help http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/introduction
- You might also want to try different js file combinations. e.g.
  individual files specific to grid kendo.grid.js or the
  kendo.all.min.js etc.
- See the Console in chrome if it shows any javascript errors. Or right
  click in chrome and inspect element to see its css.